# In java, what's the difference between 'for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {array[i] = <null or 0>}' and 'array = new <datatype>[array.length]'?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

In my code there's an instance where I must continuosly reset the values of an int array to 0 before the next iteration. Currently I just do:

```
array = new int[array.length];
```

Is this a good thing or should I use a loop instead? It seems like a very convenient shortcut to be without side effects.

Comment: One reuses an existing array, whereas the other creates a new one. Creating new arrays could put more pressure on the GC, but it probably won't have significant impact: short-lived object creations and GC is extremely fact. But if you prefer the second one, then use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill-int:A-int-

Comment: @JB Nizet - agree, but let us mention that `fill` is still using loop inside

Comment: hmm honestly I can't even think off the top of my head a use case where I'd have an array that would need frequent resets

Comment: there sure are (can be) *side effects* - if the array is being used somewhere else you will end up having disjoint arrays (creating a new one) - if that is good or not, even desired, depends on use case

Comment: I like the point of the question so I upvoted it. I am not sure why it collects downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems like a very convenient shortcut to be without side effects...

isn't creation of new array every time a side effect? Even with primitives it will singificantly affect the performace of your application if you need to do this many times

You should use a loop instead